# Where is Sets, Collections in python3

Tags: python-3.x, set

In the vein of converting some ipython notebooks to jupyter and python3
I'm stumbling over the following two lines in my notebook:

```
from sets import Set
from collections import defaultdict
```

Where do I find them for Python3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - can't import Set from sets ("no module named sets")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028204/python-cant-import-set-from-sets-no-module-named-sets)

Answer (score 3):

The `sets` module is [deprecated since Python 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). You need to use the builtin types [`set` and `frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead.

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is alive and well in Python 3, so you shouldn't need to change anything.