# Set vs. set python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's the difference between `set("a")` and `sets.Set("a")`? Their types are different, but they seem to do the same thing.

I can't find any resources online about it, but I've seen both used in examples.

Answer (score 12):

You've tagged this Python 3, so the difference is that `sets` doesn't exist. Use `set`.

In Python 2, the difference is that `sets` is deprecated. It's the old, slow, not-as-good version. Use `set`. This is explained in the [documentation for the `sets` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), which comes up instantly on a search for `Python sets`.

Answer (score 4):

The built in set() was based on the old sets.Set() and runs faster.

Both 'do' the same thing, though in Python 3 the 'sets' module no longer exists.

**Here is the answer directly from The Python 2 Library:**

The built-in set and frozenset types were designed based on lessons learned from the sets module. The key differences are:

**Set and ImmutableSet were renamed to set and frozenset.**
  
  
- There is no equivalent to BaseSet. Instead, use isinstance(x, (set, frozenset)).

  
- The hash algorithm for the built-ins performs significantly better (fewer collisions) for most datasets.

 
 - The built-in versions have more space efficient pickles.

  
- The built-in versions do not have a union_update() method. Instead, use the update() method which is equivalent.

  
- The built-in versions do not have a _repr(sorted=True) method. Instead, use the built-in repr() and sorted() functions: repr(sorted(s)).

  
- The built-in version does not have a protocol for automatic conversion to immutable. Many found this feature to be confusing and no one in the community reported having found real uses for it.

Answer (score 0):

Set is built in now, and can be used without having to import the 'sets' module explicitly.

Reference:

[Python - can't import Set from sets ("no module named sets")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028204/python-cant-import-set-from-sets-no-module-named-sets)

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference, and you should use the builtin `set` or `frozenset` , instead of `sets` module.

The sets module [documentation itself says](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) -

> Deprecated since version 2.6: The built-in set/frozenset types replace this module.

And there is no `sets` module in Python 3.x , only Python 2 .