# "No module named sets" ren'py

Tags: renpy, pythomnic3k

ok, I'm translating a game, a visual novel called "katawa shoujo", to be
precise the beta of this game which is not in Spanish
I got the beta files and moved them to ren'py (where it was created) but when running it inside ren'py I get this error:

````
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop/game/ui_ingamemenu.rpy", line 1, in script
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop/game/ui_ingamemenu.rpy", line 1, in script
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop/game/ui_ingamemenu.rpy", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sets

-- Full Traceback ------------------------------------------------------------

Full traceback:
  File "renpy/bootstrap.py", line 326, in bootstrap
    renpy.main.main()
  File "renpy/main.py", line 515, in main
    renpy.game.context().run(node)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop/game/ui_ingamemenu.rpy", line 1, in script
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop/game/ui_ingamemenu.rpy", line 1, in script
  File "renpy/ast.py", line 923, in execute
    renpy.python.py_exec_bytecode(self.code.bytecode, self.hide, store=self.store)
  File "renpy/python.py", line 2235, in py_exec_bytecode
    exec(bytecode, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop/game/ui_ingamemenu.rpy", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sets

Windows-10-10.0.19041
Ren'Py 7.4.8.1895
 
Sat Sep 25 20:22:04 2021"

I suppose that the error is in the files of the program by the address of folders that it marks:

```While running game code:
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop/game/ui_ingamemenu.rpy", line 1, in script"

but it marks that the user is "anthony" but my user is "A" ... I am very lazy with names xd
I don't have much experience so I would like you to help me, thank you


by the way, I use Atom to edit the scripts


If you need the files, I leave a download link for these:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/10ld61gyzipn0ar/Katawa_Shoujo_Beta_%2528Proyecto_de_traduccion%2529.rar/file?fbclid=IwAR14jNyYJbyyhaS6S2XEU2re5zD6Af2plIyhV40F9hH7ammfE_qaRIfJTVs
````

Answer (score 0):

I would enter the file it is mentioning and remove the line importing set. I'm guessing this is a very old beta, right? In updated versions of Python you no longer need to import the "set" library, since it's automatically included (can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028204/python-cant-import-set-from-sets-no-module-named-sets)).
If you don't have prior programming experience: Open the file named "ui_ingamemenu.rpy". On line 1 there should be a line that says "import sets". Just delete that. However, it's hard to know the exact issue without knowing the files you're working with.

Renpy doesn't display errors all at once, though; it stops at the first one it detects. So once you fix this, more may appear.

Buena suerte :)

Comment: thanks for answering, yes, the beta is an old version, I've seen in several places that the problem is "set" as you indicate, but I can't locate it, 
in the same way I cannot locate "ui_ingamemenu.rpy", 
I really would like to receive more in-depth help if possible, I can even provide the files for you to revices if needed c:

Comment: I can even provide the files for you to revices if needed

Comment: Yes, seeing the files you're using would be helpful to detect the problem! I'd put a link to those in your main post. :)

Comment: oh thank you very much seriously, let me provide you with the download link of the files c:

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/10ld61gyzipn0ar/Katawa_Shoujo_Beta_%2528Proyecto_de_traduccion%2529.rar/file?fbclid=IwAR14jNyYJbyyhaS6S2XEU2re5zD6Af2plIyhV40F9hH7ammfE_qaRIfJTVs

Comment: Yep, I found it. I'm on a Mac so I'm not sure if it's different for you, but when I downloaded that, it created a file called "Katawa Shoujo Beta". From there, click on the "game" folder. There should be a lot of .rpy and .rpyc files in there. Near the bottom there is a file named ui_ingamemenu.rpy, and at the top of that file is a line that says "import sets". Just delete that and this problem will be solved, can't promise others won't pop up though.

Comment: Fuck, it worked, thank you very much brother, you do not know how much I appreciate it c:

Answer (score 0):

A few things could cause this:

1. There could be something wrong with the name of one of your folders. Maybe a special symbol or character in the name of the folders?
2. Older versions of Python demanded you to import a library name sets, but this is now included in the standard library and can generate that error. Browse the code and look for something like: `from sets import Set as set`. If you find, delete or comment out this line. You can use ctrl + f to open the search bar.